# Display one row and get the count of total rows having same u_id

Tags: mysql

I have a table in database with following structure

```
id u_id number game score status
1   2    123   COC   214   active
2   2    535   BF4   13    active
3   3    334   GOW3  123   active
4   2    655   AC3   79    inactive
```

however I want to get the data such that each row must have a unique u_id and include a column which shows the number of times this u_id is available in database table but only where status is active.

```
id u_id count
 1   2   2
 2   3   1
```

Thanks

Comment: Your example does not match your explanation or I don't get it

Comment: select count(id) group by u_id where status = 'active'

Comment: sorry, just a mistake.  corrected it. see the second table now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select min(id) as id, u_id, count(*) as count
from your_table
where status = 'active'
group by u_id
```

Comment: what is the purpose of min(id)

Comment: To get the lowest `id`  for each `u_id`. You should aggregate all columns that you don't group by. MySQL allows otherwise, but it is bad practice and other DB engines throw an error if you don't do it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID , U_ID , COUNT(*)
  FROM MyTable
 GROUP BY ID,U_ID ;
```